# Db session using SQLAlchemy is erroring out with parallel calls

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have created a db_session like this:

```
db_engine = create_engine(DB_URL, pool_pre_ping=True, echo=False, pool_size=POOL_SIZE, max_overflow=MAX_OVERFLOW)
Base.metadata.create_all(db_engine)
db_session = sessionmaker(bind=db_engine)()
```

I am using this db_session in one of the Flask route defined as:

```
from db_settings import db_session

@application.route('/'):
def my_home():
    try:
        my_obj = MyObj("dummy_fname", "dummy_lname")
        db_session.merge(my_obj)
        db_session.commit()
    except exc.IntegrityError:
        db_session.rollback()
    finally:
        db_session.close()
```

I was expecting the db_session to be independent for each hit to the route. I tried to hit the route sequentially one after the other for 5 times and it created 5 entries into db, without any issue. But when i tried to hit the same endpoint parallelly using threading, it only created one entry in db and the rest four calls errored out. Can someone help me to understand the situation. Why this is happening. Is the `db_session.close()` affecting the rest of the api calls??

```
import requests
import threading

no_parallel_hits = no_of_sequential_hits = 5


def send_request():
    url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/'
    response = requests.get(url)
    print(response.text)


def main_parallel():
    threads = []
    for _ in range(no_parallel_hits):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=send_request)
        threads.append(thread)
        thread.start()

    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()


def main_sequential():
    for _ in range(no_of_sequential_hits):
        send_request()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main_parallel()
    # main_sequential()
```

This is what i tried. main_sequential() call is working fine, whereas main_parallel() is not working as expected

Answer (score 0):

Right here you make a session maker and then make a single session instance.
This instance isn't meant to be used concurrently or to be at the global scope.

```py
# Usually NOT what you want.
db_session = sessionmaker(bind=db_engine)()
```

It would be better to do something like this:

```
db_session_maker = sessionmaker(bind=db_engine)
```

Then make a session like this:

```py
from db_settings import db_session_maker

@application.route('/'):
def my_home():
    db_session = db_session_maker()
    try:
        my_obj = MyObj("dummy_fname", "dummy_lname")
        db_session.add(my_obj)
        db_session.commit()
    except exc.IntegrityError:
        db_session.rollback()
    finally:
        db_session.close()
```

Even better would be to use some sort of flask session manager to handle the creating and closing for you.  SQLAlchemy has a note about separating the session management from your application code.
[session-faq-whentocreate](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_basics.html#session-faq-whentocreate)

Also you should use `db_session.add` to add new objects and not `db_session.merge` which is for a different purpose.